# Expected argument of type "string", MyEntity given

Tags: symfony

I faced a problem when created a dropdown (category, subcategory) instead of input text fields in FormBuilderInterface
When I change it back to text input all working good.

Here is my code for FormType

```
namespace Expatservice\ManagerBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ServiceType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('category', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'ExpatserviceCategoryBundle:Category',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                    ->where('c.parent = 0')
                    ->orderBy('c.title', 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_value' => 'title',
                'choice_label' => 'title'
            ))
            ->add('subcategory', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'ExpatserviceCategoryBundle:Category',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                    ->where('c.parent = 2')
                    ->orderBy('c.title', 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_value' => 'title',
                'choice_label' => 'title'
            ))
            ->add('description')
            ->add('image', FileType::class, array('data_class' => null, 'required'=>false));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaultOptions(array('data_class' => 'Expatservice\ManagerBundle\Entity\Service'));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'expantservice_managerbundle_service';
    }
}
```

I understand the problem, but can't figure out how to fix it and don't found nothing in internet.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you tell us what line the error is occurring on and point out the line. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure I understand correctly, but have the entity in question implemented the '__toString()'-function?

Comment: Alvin, the exact string is: "Expected argument of type "string", "Expatservice\CategoryBundle\Entity\Category" given"

UnexpectedTypeException: 
if (!is_scalar($value) && !(is_object($value) && method_exists($value, '__toString'))) {
     throw new UnexpectedTypeException($value, 'string');
}

$stringValue = (string) $value;

Comment: pusle, it's not inplemented the __toString() function

Comment: Ok, I've added __toString() method after title getter and it's start work. Thanks for right course, pusle.

Comment: Hi @AntonArtemev .  I see you are new to stackoverflow. When responding to people, use the '@' sign in front of their name so we actually get a message. I didn't see any messages from you, so I just checked back now. So I have a question: Is your problem solved? If so, can you post the answer and mark it as correct? If not, can you also edit your post to show the code that you included in your comments? I don't understand where that goes. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @AlvinBunk, thanks for support. Yes my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should use __toString() magic function to get right data type when handle my form submitting.

To be sure that we'll get string, Entity part should look like this:

```
/**
 * Get title
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}

public function __toString() {
    return $this->title;
}
```